# How to get a form to build a FormData() object without using an id as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I'm trying to get a form that is inside a "modal-body" div and create a FormData() object when the user clicks on a modal button. For special reasons I can't get this form by id or class, so I'm doing it like this:

```
$('.save-form').click(function() {
    var myform = $(this).parent().parent().find('.modal-body').html();
    var fd = new FormData(myform);
}
```

By using .html() or .contents() I get the error: "**Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'**".

It works fine if I use an id as a selector, but as I said I cannot get it by it's id. Apparently FormData() is not liking what I'm passing to it. So my question is: Do I need to get the form thru another way or do I need to make a conversion or something first? I will appreciate any help.

This is my html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">My Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="item-1">
                        <label>Item 1</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="item-2">
                        <label>Item 2</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="item-3">
                        <label>Item 3</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="item-4">
                        <label>Item 4</label>
                    </form>            
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-form">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `.html()` and `contents()` methods on `<input>`s? What are you trying to get with FormData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use plain JavaScript or de-reference the jQuery Object when referencing the `<form>` tag. FormData() Object does not recognize jQuery Objects. Any of the following should work:

**De-reference jQuery Object**

```
$('form')[0];
$('form').get(0);
```

**Plain JavaScript**

```
document.forms[0];
document.querySelector('form');
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
```

All of the above will get the first `<form>` tag on the webpage without any attributes.

#### Demo

```js
$('.save-form').click(function() {
  const form = $('form')[0];
  const fd = new FormData(form);
  console.log(fd);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xModal">
  Modal
</button>

<div id="xModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">My Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item-1">
            <label>Item 1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item-2">
            <label>Item 2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item-3">
            <label>Item 3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item-4">
            <label>Item 4</label>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-form">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```